# newbie trying to return 2d array from fastcsv but returning undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, csv

I have this code here

```
function marketInfo() {
    var market_data = [];
    csv
    .fromPath("market_info.csv")
    .on("data", function(data) {
        if (data.length != 0) {
            market_data.push(data);
        }
    })
    .on("end", function() {
        for (var i=0; i < market_data.length; i++) {
            result.push(market_data[i]);
        }
        // console.log(market_data);
        return market_data;
    })
}
```

It prints the data and I know someone mentioned something about callbacks in another post, but I don't quite understand... The data has 0 headers so it's inline with [['market_cap', '123456789']] and so on. When returning the array, it's undefined. I tried to search but I can't figure out whats the issue here

Comment: Is this Node.js?

Comment: Yeah im using nodejs with express/ejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `return market_data` function just yells into the void. It does nothing meaningful. The `marketInfo` function itself makes use of asynchronous code with callbacks. Unless you supply a callback to that function you have no way of capturing that return value.

```
function marketInfo(cb) {
    var market_data = [];
    csv
    .fromPath("market_info.csv")
    .on("data", function(data) {
        if (data.length != 0) {
            market_data.push(data);
        }
    })
    .on("end", function() {
        for (var i=0; i < market_data.length; i++) {
            result.push(market_data[i]);
        }
        // console.log(market_data);
        cb(null, market_data);
    })
}
```

Where your callback needs to be passed in:

```
marketInfo(function(err, market_data) {
  // Do stuff with data
});
```

As writing callback-driven code can be harrowing you might try and steer towards solutions based around either Promises or `async`/`await` instead.

Comment: As an advanced user of java/python, which would you recommend learning in regards to industry standards? Promises or is the cb sufficient enough?

Comment: The JavaScript community has a diversity of opinions on the subject and that's largely because there's conflicting use cases. If you're doing browser-side code that needs to support IE10+ then you can't use any of the new ES6 features that make life easier. If you're doing Node.js code on the current build you can make use of *everything*. The [MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) usually has a good overview of what's possible, not necessarily what's *best*.

Comment: Personally I think Promises and `async`/`await` makes life *considerably* easier, but that's just my opinion. I do appreciate the work that projects like [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) and [Mocha](https://mochajs.org) have done to fully promise-ize their code because `async`/`await` bolts right on top of that seamlessly.

Comment: Sorry to be a bother again, but I understand there are no returns, but how do I pass dynamic content through my index.js to my index.ejs file? I can't seem to do that without having a return feature available to me

Comment: @ImranChowdhry It's best to ask that as a new question rather than chaining on to this one.